# How to replace function name with a babel plugin

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Is it possible to create a Babel plugin that will change a function's name?

I can't seem to find this in the documentation.

Example:

```js
    myObject.doSomething() ==> babel ==> myObject.___doSomething()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the AST of your code in [astexplorer](https://astexplorer.net/). And you can see it's about a CallExpression and MemberExpression. So search babel-types API in [babel-types source code](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-types/src/definitions/), it's very clear of how to create a babel type or judge a babel-type like this:

```js
    defineType("MemberExpression", {
      builder: ["object", "property", "computed"],
      visitor: ["object", "property"],
      aliases: ["Expression", "LVal"],
      fields: {
        object: {
          validate: assertNodeType("Expression")
        },
        property: {
          validate(node, key, val) {
            let expectedType = node.computed ? "Expression" : "Identifier";
            assertNodeType(expectedType)(node, key, val);
          }
        },
        computed: {
          default: false
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are two different ways to do it (either with the Program visitor **or** with the FunctionDeclaration visitor):

```js
    export default function ({types: t}) {
      return {
        visitor: {
          Program(path) {
            path.scope.rename('doSomething', '___doSomething');
          },
          FunctionDeclaration(path) {
            if (path.node.id.name === 'doSomething') {
              path.node.id.name = '___doSomething'
            }
          }
        }
      };
    }
```

Note that these are not safe since they can override an existing name. You can use the `path.scope.generateUidIdentifier("uid");` command to generate a unique identifier and use that but you won't be able to define the generated name.

Example - http://astexplorer.net/#/o5NsNwV46z/1